# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in BizTalk project

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-pipelines

I have a solution that contains three `BizTalk` projects named BizTalk.Schemas, BizTalk.Pipelines and BizTalk.Archive.Component.

When I am Rebuilding the solution, It is throwing error of "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**" in pipelines(.btp) under BizTalk.Pipelines project.

I have added all the reference in the respective project but still it is giving the same error.

Can anyone help me that what i am missing in pipelines(.btp)?

Comment: Please add break points in your solution and debug your program.

Comment: When I am building the project (Compile time), at that time error occurs.

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem in a custom pipeline component, probably in the Load() or Save() method of your component.

Comment: I think you have a custom pipeline component that makes your pipeline crash, you have to know that when you build your solution the write and read method of your custom pipeline get executed so the error for sure come from one of those methods post the code and we will have more info

Answer (score 0):

Looks like visual studio issue to me. try unloading and loading the project again. which Visual studio version are you using?